# how can i print a graph path with so many linkages using dijkstram?

Tags: perl, graph

I have undirected graph with 57 nodes and 204 linkages. I calculate the shortest path of all nodes with its sub nodes using Dijkstram algorithm, but I couldn't able to print the path of the nodes from a given root. here is how i tried.

```
########## the dijkstram algorithm#################
sub dijkstra {
    my ($graph, $root) = @_;
    my (%dist, %prev);

    foreach $n (keys %{$graph}) { $dist{$n} = inf; $prev{$n}=$n; }
    # .. except the source
    $dist{$root} = 0;

    # loop while we have unsolved nodes
    # sort unsolved by distance from root
    foreach my $n1 (sort keys %{$graph}) {
        foreach my $n2 (keys %{$graph->{$n1}}) {
            if (($dist{$n2} eq inf)) {
                $dist{$n2} = $dist{$n1} + $graph->{$n1}{$n2};
                $prev{$n2} = $n1;
            }
        }
    }
    return (\%prev, \%dist);
}
######## print the path and the distance for a given node#############
sub printPaths {
    my ($graph, $prev, $dist) = @_;
    my $path;

    foreach $n (keys %{$graph}) {
        my $t = $n;
        $path = $t;
        while ($t ne $root) {
            $t = $prev->{$t}; $path = "$t -> " . $path;
        }
        print "$n\t$dist->{$n}\t$path\n";
    }
}
```

the problem occurs on the while loop. when it gets a node that doesn't have the same root and when the previous node always returns the same node. please help me or give me any suggestion. thanks

Comment: To help anyone help you, please provide working (directly runnable) example, perhaps with small data set.

Comment: its Dijkstra - without the 'm'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caveat: I have no experience in your problem domain, so this may not be an answer per se. However this my provide some pointers as to where problems may lie (hopefully).

I ran your code with the following data set in prot.ini:

```
ARR1 MafB
MafB JunD
ARR1 MET4
ARR1 ATF1
ARR1 BACH1
ARR1 CHOP 
ATF1 BACH1
ATF1 MET4
ATF1 NFE2L1
ATF2 ATF7
ATF2 BATF
```

(removed hypens for readability!)

after the dijkstra function %prev looks like this:

```
$prev = {
          'ATF1' => 'ARR1',
          'MafB' => 'ARR1',
          'BACH1' => 'ARR1',
          'BATF' => 'ATF2',     # problem here
          'ATF2' => 'BATF',     # values are cyclic
          'CHOP' => 'ARR1',
          'ARR1' => 'ARR1',
          'JunD' => 'MafB',
          'NFE2L1' => 'ATF1',
          'ATF7' => 'ATF2',      
          'MET4' => 'ARR1'
        };
```

In your print_path the while loop $t endlessly alternates between 'BATF' and 'ATF2'.

You could detect for this in the print_path function - but I ended up adding the following line in the dijkstra function to prevent the cyclic issues:

```
if (($dist{$node2} eq inf)) {
  $dist{$node2} = $dist{$node1} + $graph->{$node1}{$node2};
  if ($prev{$node1} ne $node2) {
    $prev{$node2} = $node1;
  }
}
```

then i modified the while loop in the print_path function:

```
while ($tmp ne $root) {
    $tmp = $prev->{$tmp};
    last unless $tmp;
    $path = "$tmp -> $path";
}
```

Also i notice that in this line:

```
$dist{$node2} = $dist{$node1} + $graph->{$node1}{$node2};
```

$dist{$node1} could be infinity: so the result will still be infinity. Not sure if that is intentional.

Hope this helps.